# Determine Signal R connection status without broadcasting Clients.All.someMethod() and blowing up client side resources

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm concerned about using `Clients.All` in my C# Signal R hub class

```
Clients.All.setConnectionStatus(profileId, true);
```

I'm calling it in both `OnConnected()` and `OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)`
to show the online status of my logged in users.
`OnDisconnected()` isn't as bad because it's only being called when someone actually logs off

ex.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
   string profileId = Context.User.Identity.Name;
   _connections.Add(profileId, Context.ConnectionId);
    Clients.All.setConnectionStatus(profileId, true);
    return base.OnConnected();
 }

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    string profileId = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    _connections.Remove(profileId, Context.ConnectionId);
    if (stopCalled == false) // log off only
        Clients.All.setConnectionStatus(profileId, false);
     return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

My concern -> Blowing up the users machine client side with javascript code constantly running in the browser!

Scenario -> If I have > ~1000 users online and logged in traversing to different pages, I will be broadcasting to all of them a signal R connection `Clients.All.setConnectionStatus(profileId, true);`

which in the javascript hub looks like this below which could easily end up blowing up the users browser, because it would be constantly receiving these broadcasting connection status calls!!!

```js
scope.chat = $.connection.chatHub;

// Receive and set the connection status
scope.chat.client.setConnectionStatus = function(profileId, isConnected) {
  // look for prfileId in html
  var $profileStatusElement = $(".online-status-profile[data-id='" + profileId + "']");
  var $profileChatElement = $(".online-status-chat[data-id='" + profileId + "']");
  
  if (isConnected === true) {
    // change the online status
  } else {
    // change the online status
  }
};
```

I have chat windows to users (online) like below that shows a users status next to their name. So I know if the person I'm sending a message to is online or not!

When I first load the chatbox, I fetch the online status server side, but after that it's up to the `OnConnected()` and `OnDisconnected()` methods in my hub to set the online status of the person I'm chatting with.

[image]

There's got to be a better way then broadcasting the signal out to 'all' online users on my site? But the only way I can think of is to poll the status every so often on some javascript timer, but I hate that idea!!

Another way would be to keep some kind of in-memory collection of who each person is chatting with, but that seems like it could get really messy and could end up up not being very accurate, being there could be so many things in between the client and server that could cause a disruption to mismanage the in-memory collection of who's connected to whom! Any thoughts or ideas here would be greatly appreciated!!

FYI -> I also have a messages page, that shows a list of all the recent conversations I've had with users like below. And on this page I show the online status of these users as well. On this page I fetch the online status of each user on the server before I render the page, same as the chat box, but once the page is loaded, it's up to the `OnConnected()` and `OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)` to set the online status of each user on the page.

[image]

Comment: Does the online status need to be updated only when the chat window is open or always?

Comment: Hi Aamir. To answer you, the chat window can be open or minimized. In these two scenarios, the status is always updated. But keep in mind I also have a profile page for each user and it too shows the online status that would be updated always. And, from the screen shot above, I have a messages page where a user can view their most recent messages/chats with other profiles. This page also shows the online status of each of the users from recent chats. This would be updated always as well.

Comment: What makes you think it will blow the client resources?
As i  understand, you need to change the status at client, so has to be done by the client script.. How often do the status changes happen?

Comment: here's a hypothetical. What if I have 10,000 users online, logged in and traversing to different pages. With each page load/refresh a new broadcast gets sent out to each and every single online user. So thousands and thousands of receiving calls on the client side will be handled constantly.

Comment: Understood. What if instead of updating clients directly, you can maintain an in-memory collections of online and offline users and periodically update the clients? You can control the interval when the clients are updated.

Comment: Hi Aamir, yes, if you look at my post you'll see that I proposed that as an option, but feel it might get messy under certain circumstances. So I'm looking to see if someone can propose a solid solution (type of collection, how it would be used, etc) for that option or another option entirely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183539/discussion-between-aamir-masood-and-user1186050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing in right way with signalR. I guide you based on your concerns/scenarios:

> My concern -> Blowing up the users machine client side with javascript
>   code constantly running in the browser!

Don't forget that you are using a browser underlying functionality (WebSocket), so we have no choice unless *running some js code inside client loaded page*. You take advantage of browser capabilities here.

> Scenario -> If I have > ~1000 users online and logged in traversing to
>   different pages, I will be broadcasting to all of them a signal R
>   connection `Clients.All.setConnectionStatus(profileId, true);`

Before proposing any solution, I exhort you to [employ grouping logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) in your application. *Grouping reduces the volume of synchronizations*.

If you working on a *public chat room* (which can contain large number of people), by employing server side strategies simply you'll make your code to a dirty one! Yes, Any user who navigates or refreshes the page can cause a redundant update to all the clients. **Best Solution is** *turning you page to SPA* (working with API call or Ajax call) with no page refresh. *I believe that any real-time web application should take advantage of modern web technologies*. This will solve almost every problem which you suffer (e.g no page refresh, no reRun, no disCoennection & etc ...).

Solutions like using a js timer to fetch latest status for users is not clean or desirable.

Comment: Hi Amirhossein. Grouping will in fact work, but in order for me to apply grouping logic to Signal R I will have to devise a grouping logic on the server side with who's connected to whom! This is one of my proposed options above! If you have any idea on how this can be implemented, so I don't have to broadcast out to 'All' users in my 'OnConnected' and 'OnDiconnected' methods in the signal hub, please propose the logic in your answer.

Comment: @user1186050 It's not a good idea to use Grouping logic without implementing something like room in client-side. But the only way which can reduce updates is to handle users which are shown in chat list with 10 people less or more. Or grouping them based on chat history. If you are interested, I can append it to my answer.